# Consultar linha da tabela e "rankeando"

Tags: php, tabela-html

Estou criando uma série de perfis, e quero criar uma espécie de **ranking baseado no número de visitas**.

Eu já criei o *script* para somar visitas e já está tudo certo na tabela `users`.

```
User_id|User_cover|User_name|User_content|User_pais|User_facebook|User_date|**User_views**
```

O `User_views` soma a cada visualização. Acontece que eu queria mostrar o resultado da consulta e calcular pela coluna `User_views` a **posição na tabela** que esse usuário esta. Retornando um número para exibição no HTML.

Eu consigo fazer isso sem *script* ou terei de adaptar? E se tiver que fazer isso, qual a lógica que preciso executar?

Comment: Amigo, poste o que você já tem, pretende salvar os dados em uma base de dados provavelmente, correto? Explique melhor qual a sua dúvida.. ou deseja somente consultar o site do facebook?

Comment: Veja bem,essa tabela acima é um cadastro com dados do usuário,o facebook é só um link para o pessoal ser amigo dele.
-Vamos supor que o usuário x tem 430 visitas e outro usuário y com 500 visitas, eu queria através de uma query ou algo do tipo mostrar a posição na coluna "User_views" que soma as visitas. Então quando o usuário acessar o perfil x,aparecer no ranking como 2º ou algo do tipo.Sem usar outra tabela para isso. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Entendi mais ou menos, então... existem centenas de formas de se fazer algo do tipo, existem muitos frameworks em PHP que ajudam a construção, fica meio que aberto essa idéia de "como fazer?" o mais correto seria você chegar com uma idéia pelo menos um pouco já bem formulada, e pedir um aconselhamento

Comment: So mais um ponto, a sua dúvida fica em cima da consulta do banco de dados em si, ou fica na parte de aplicação?

Comment: É na consulta mesmo, desculpe,tens razõ,fica muito amplo mesmo.É a consulta,eu queria algo bem otimizado,o site é bem robusto.

Answer (score 1):

Pode trazer essa coluna já do SQL. Basta criar uma coluna temporária com auto increment e fazer um order by user_views.
Segue um exemplo em MySql:

```
SELECT
  (@count := @count + 1) AS ranking,
  users.*
FROM users
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @count := 0) AS dummy
ORDER BY users.user_views DESC;
```